# Compile the same program but get different binaries in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I doesn`t have much to do with Delphi but I need to compare the hash of two binaries of the same source code in Delphi XE.
To my suprise both binaries differs at many points so the hash is not equal.
Did anyone can push me in the right direction what can happen there?

Comment: Linker timestamp is enough to cause avalanche effect in the hash sum.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2013312/224704 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1829533/224704 (possibly more)